# Trying to make a aspx page a registered only space

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I am trying to create a page where only logon people can enter.
This is my code currently in my Quiz.aspx and my Global.asax

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    if (Session["username"] == null)
    {
        Session["username"] = "Guest";
    }
}
```

Quiz.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)Session["username"]=="Guest")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error? Is the application doing nothing? Is it not redirecting properly?

Comment: When the user logs in, It is becoming guest again and I cannot access Quiz.aspx.

Comment: Are you setting `Session["username"]` in `Login.aspx`? Perhaps there is an issue in that logic?

Comment: I set 'Session["username"]' In 'Login.aspx' if the guy successfully logs in. After he successfully logs in and tries to access 'Quiz.aspx', the session turns to Guest again.

Comment: Are you using a LogIn control? Which event are you using to add user to session?

Comment: Using data reader and if it finds rows, it gives a session[“username”] with it's username.